# Wkhtmltopdf encoding issue in C# mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert html to pdf. The issues are fonts with charaters like č,š,ž,đ (those are charaters used by Serbian, Croatian, Slovenian language). They are not displayed coretly in pdf. Html renders correctly.

This is how my html is constructed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Export</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>č,š,ž,đ</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

In my C# code where I am using wkhtmptopdf i do this

```
        Process p;
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = HtmlToPdfExePath;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);

        // run the conversion utility
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        // note: that we tell wkhtmltopdf to be quiet and not run scripts
        string args = "-q -n ";
        args += "--disable-smart-shrinking ";
        args += "--orientation Portrait ";
        args += "--outline-depth 0 ";
        args += "--page-size A4 ";
        args += "--encoding utf-8";
        args += " - -";

        psi.Arguments = args;

        p = Process.Start(psi);
```

So as you can see I am using utf-8 encoding on html and wkhtmltopdf as argument but the charaters do not render corectly. What am I missing? Below is what i get in pdf. English characters renders normaly.

[image: This is pdf as image]

Comment: If you have chrome installed, open your html in chrome and see if it renders correctly. Its possible you do not have the fonts installed on the target machine that wkhtml is running on.

Comment: html renders correctly. Only pdf doesn not.

Comment: Everything here looks fine. Show us your code for passing the HTML in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default encoding for redirected streams is defined by your default code page. You need to set it to UTF-8.

Unfortunately `Process` doesn't let you do this, so you need to make your own `StreamWriter`:

```
StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I happen to have been doing exactly what you're doing, for the past two weeks ;). Here's another helpful hint: wkhtmltopdf.exe, on Windows at least, is not safe to run concurrently. Its print driver crashes.

Comment: how do you mean concurently...like two or more users at the same time?

Comment: Running two or more processes of the exe at the same time. Not sure about users specifically.

Comment: If its any help: I ran my mvc 4 web project under windows 8 in VS 2012. Opened two tabs in firefox and then as quickly as i can use my mouse :) pressed export icon on first tab and then on second. No problems. I do not know if this test is exactly what you had in mind.

Comment: Concurrency issues are sometimes difficult to replicate. With 2 concurrent processes, I could sometimes get through 2000 pages without any apparent issue. With 4 I was lucky to get to 200.

Comment: well...if money is not a big problem you can still buy this http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx. I was testing it and it looks a lot better that Wkhtmltopdf. Many people say support is also superb. I also will go to this product if Wkhtmltopdf will be causing some serious problems